# User Block " Startup Apllications"

Tags: 18.04, users

1. Is there a way, to block access to settings for users to "startup applications". I have programs that sync with drive and I don't want the user to disable them.
2. Can the toolbar also be blocked? so that the user does not modify it.

All this is in ubuntu 18.04

Thank you!

Comment: Each user should have their own account, their own toolbar, and their own "startup applications." Don't let other folks use your (admin) account.

Answer (score 0):

each user has their account, the only one with root privileges is me. In this way, they can still modify the start of applications, as well as the toolbar